# AAD user provisioning with custom SCIM app

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, provisioning

I'm implementing the user provisioning with AAD using custom app. I'm following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups and able to get user's basic data but unable to get manager information.
I've designed the schema as per instructions and successfully test it with POSTMAN.

Now, I'm here and I need your help.

any help must be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the user's manager already provisioned into the application via AAD Provisioning? The only way that the AAD provisioning service knows how to translate the representation of a user's manager from an AAD ObjectId into a SCIM ID value is if it is also in scope for the AAD provisioning service.